# Push notification different Messages for different servers ios

Tags: php, ios, json, push-notification

I have set up many push notifications in iOS projects. I always receive the same message which I have sent from my application, all going well.

But when I change my server from my local machine (or a dedicated server) to web hosting the message format changes somewhat. For which we are not accepting.

Sample message from our server:

```
{"msg":"match found !","match_id":"34","rqst":"1"}
```

Sample message from web hosting server (remote server) :

```
{\"msg\":\"Match found !\",\"match_id\":\"34\",\"rqst\":\"1\"}
```

It contains extra backslashes before and after every string.

FYI we are using Slim Framework with PHP MySQL APIs, and the messages sent are JSON.

Comment: Looks like you have 'magic quotes' enabled on your web hosting.

Comment: Share some of the PHP code that generates the content.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP to get ride of the slashes before sending the message.

```
<?php stripslashes($YourMessage); ?>
```

Comment: why its coming well on my local server ? and having problem in web hosting.

Comment: Do you have the same frame work on on both servers? Are the messages that are sent or received?